# Safari is not launching in mac book pro even after enabling remote automation and node is connected to the hub

Tags: macos, testing, selenium-webdriver, safari, launch

With selenium grid and TestNG, I am trying to launch safari in mac book pro. Hub is connected. Safari node is launched. I have enabled the "enable remote automation" in Developer menu. Closed all safari windows. The test cases start running. But safari is not launching. But in the test console we could see the message that safari is launching with desired capabilities. But after some time the message will be could not start new browser session.

I have tried changing the hub and node.I tried changing the parameters in the safari node .I tried with just one test case i.e:

```
WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
driver.get("http://www.makeseleniumeasy.com");
```

So the Safari has launched.But with hub and Node it is not launching. I suspect whether the error is with the safari node or @Test code. Please help me with this.

I have also tried adding `System.setproperty` in the setup by giving the path for safari driver

*safari.command:*

```
Java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -nodeConfig grid_safari.json
```

/*safarinode */

"capabilities":
"browserName": "safari",
"maxInstances": 1,
"seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
Expected result is safari browser should launch but it is not launching.

/*Setup.test*/

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.safari.driver");  
drivernew=DesiredCapabilities.safari();         
drivernew.setBrowserName("safari");          
drivernew.setPlatform(Platform.MAC);
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add details, do not put code in comments

Comment: I have edited my question . Is there anybody to help me with this?

Comment: If the New Session command failed, then you need to include the error message. Otherwise, how could we know what went wrong without doing a ton of work to re-type your commands?